# Python (RenPy): Textbuttons executing a function they don't explicitly call every time they're pressed

Tags: python, renpy

In the game I'm working on, I use an array to track the current stats of the player's company, and the following function to edit the array.

```
init python:

#The following store item objects, which include an array of their own stats
#Stores currently owned equipment
   Equipment = []
#Stores items available to buy
   Items = []
#Stores currently equipped equipment
   Equipped = []
#The company's current stats   
   SecArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

#Called whenever moving something in or out of the currently equipped items.
#Pass the current item's stat array, the stat array, and a + or - symbol
   def arrayedit(array, SecArray, symbol):
        Notify("The stats have changed")
        if symbol == "+":
            SecArray[0] += array[0]
            SecArray[1] += array[1]
            SecArray[2] += array[2]
            SecArray[3] += array[3]
            SecArray[4] += array[4]
            SecArray[5] += array[5]
        if symbol == "-":
            SecArray[0] -= array[0]
            SecArray[1] -= array[1]
            SecArray[2] -= array[2]
            SecArray[3] -= array[3]
            SecArray[4] -= array[4]
            SecArray[5] -= array[5]
        return()
```

If any items are in the "Equipment" array, however, their stats are added to the current stats every time a textbutton is clicked (so, for example, if an item has 3 in a stat, the player's current stats will increase by 3 every time *any* button is clicked, counting infinitely upward). Similarly, if any items are in the "Equipped" array, their current stats are subtracted from the player's current stats every time a textbutton is clicked. Items in the "Items" array do not have any effect.

The following code is for windows to shop and equip/dequip equipment.

```
screen shopping1():

    frame:
        xpos (config.screen_width*25/64) ypos (config.screen_height*11/64)
        ysize (config.screen_height*31/64)
        xsize (config.screen_width*36/64)

        has side "c r b"

        viewport:
            yadjustment tutorials_adjustment
            mousewheel True

            vbox:
              xpos (config.screen_width*2/5) ypos (config.screen_height*3/16)
              ysize (config.screen_height/2)
              xsize (config.screen_width/2)
              for i in Items:
                    if i.kind == "Item":
                      if i.cost <= Money:
                          textbutton "[i.title]   $[i.cost]":
                            action [AddToSet(Equipment, i), RemoveFromSet(Items, i), Hide("shopping1"), Return(i.cost)]
                            left_padding 20
                            xfill True
                            hovered Notify(i.hover)

                    else:
                        null height 10
                        text i.title alt ""
                        null height 5

              for i in Policies:
                    if i.kind == "Policy":
                      if i.cost <= Money:
                          textbutton "[i.title]   $[i.cost]":
                            action [AddToSet(OwnedPolicies, i), RemoveFromSet(Policies, i), Hide("shopping1"), Return(i.cost)]
                            left_padding 20
                            xfill True
                            hovered Notify(i.hover)                           

                    else:
                        null height 10
                        text i.title alt ""
                        null height 5

              for i in Trainings:
                    if i.kind == "Training":
                      if i.cost <= Money:
                          textbutton "[i.title]   $[i.cost]":
                            action [AddToSet(OwnedTrainings, i), RemoveFromSet(Trainings, i), Hide("shopping1"), Return(i.cost)]
                            left_padding 20
                            xfill True
                            hovered Notify(i.hover)

                    else:
                        null height 10
                        text i.title alt ""
                        null height 5

        bar adjustment tutorials_adjustment style "vscrollbar"

        textbutton _("Return"):
            xfill True
            action [Hide("shopping1")]
            top_margin 10

screen equipmentedit():

    frame:
        xpos (config.screen_width*5/128)  ypos (config.screen_height*2/64)
        ysize (config.screen_height*47/64)
        xsize (config.screen_width*19/64)

        has side "c r b"

        viewport:
            yadjustment tutorials_adjustment
            mousewheel True

            vbox:
              null height 10
              text "Unequipped Items" alt ""
              null height 5
              for i in Equipment:

                    if i.kind == "Item":

                        textbutton "[i.title]   $[i.cost]":
                            action [arrayedit(i.stats, SecArray, "+"), AddToSet(Equipped, i), RemoveFromSet(Equipment, i), Hide("equipmentedit"), Return(i.cost)]
                            left_padding 20
                            xfill True

                    else:

                        null height 10
                        text i.title alt ""
                        null height 5
              null height 10
              text "Equipped Items" alt ""
              null height 5
              for i in Equipped:

                    if i.kind == "Item":

                        textbutton "[i.title]   $[i.cost]":
                            action [arrayedit(i.stats, SecArray, "-"), AddToSet(Equipment, i), RemoveFromSet(Equipped, i), Hide("equipmentedit"), Return(i.cost)]
                            left_padding 20
                            xfill True

                    else:

                        null height 10
                        text i.title alt ""
                        null height 5




        bar adjustment tutorials_adjustment style "vscrollbar"

        textbutton _("Return"):
            xfill True
            action [Hide("equipmentedit")]
            top_margin 10
```

Outside of this, the arrays and functions used are not called or referenced elsewhere in the program. I believe the "arrayedit" function is being called for items in the equipped and equpiment arrays every time a button is clicked, including the return buttons, but I'm unsure of why. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I noticed that arrayedit has return() instead of return. I believe that will make it return an empty tuple - is that what you want? Maybe you want to leave out the return altogether? My only guess is that maybe having it return an unexpected empty tuple is screwing things up somehow

Comment: I've tried it with return(), return, and no return statement, and none of them seem to make a difference. Initially I thought that the error was that I left out the return statement and that somehow caused it to act as it is.

Comment: Shucks, I really have no idea then, sorry! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I believe you're you're falling victim to Renpy's prediction, as demonstrated by this thread on GitHub: https://github.com/renpy/renpy/issues/3718.

Renpy runs through all the code in a screen when it's shown (and multiple other times) including searching any function calls in order to pre-load assets. Usually this shouldn't cause a problem because most of the Renpy calls utilise `renpy.restart_interaction()` which reverts any changes to variables. Unfortunately it can struggle when it comes to directly calling Python objects.

The solution I used for this was to have the screen element call an intermediate function which included the `renpy.restart_interaction()` call (for some reason putting the restart directly into my Python object's function was causing other problems).

Something like this:

```
init python:
    def intermediateFunc(funcToCall, obj, arg):
        funcToCall(obj, arg)
        renpy.restart_interaction()

screen myScreen:
    imagebutton:
        # ...
        action Function(intermediateFunc, MyObj.DoSomething, obj, "an argument")
```